# Issue animating a 3D text within a scene

Tags: animation

I'm pretty new to blender and probably missed something obvious, but I couldn't find anything online pertaining to this problem.
I recently created a small animation and I'm aware of the basics. (Add a keyframe, move the timeline, change the object in the way you want it to animate, add new keyframe, etc.)
That animation turned out perfectly, and I rendered it into a video.
A day later, I wanted to add some more to the animation.  I added some 3D text using the "text" option within blender, and positioned it appropriately.  I added a starting keyframe, then rotated the text as I wanted it.  I added a new keyframe.  The text jumped back to it's previous rotation and refuses to move itself.  The keyframe shows itself on the timeline, but no matter what I've tried, the text itself won't move.  Any help at all would be very, very appreciated!

File is here: https://pasteall.org/blend/4e39eebd0c3843298554a7d1555657e2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome, it could be better if you add some images of your settings, animation, or a blend file

Comment: Hi, thanks, how do I add a blend file to this site?  (Sorry, new to both Blender and StackExchange)

Comment: Hi, aside from blend files, it would be nice to see images as an [edit] and any other relevant information as well. This way your question remains useful to *future users* after you have received an answer. If you choose to add a file you may use [pasteall](https://pasteall.org/blend/) or [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) Also, as you are new here, please look around the [tour] and  [help center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea of how to best benefit from the site. :)

Comment: Hopefully this is better. :D

Answer (score 0):

Your animation is there, it's working for me, the only thing that i'm not sure if it's something that you did, is the Time Remapping (output Properties > Time Remapping) this is showing a new remapping of 200, so the keyframe is in Frame 130 + the time remapping = Frame 230

[image]

Comment: Oh!  When I finalized the original animation I changed that value to slow down the animation, since I wasn't sure if there was an easier way to do it.  That must have screwed up everything, thank you so much, problem fixed!